# Insert text in a List<String> fallowing a pattern

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a `List<String>` of some extracted text, and I want to verify if the list meets this criteria (could contains many times this pattern and every one is an item in the list):

```
0      // A zero should always be here when two numbers are together
\r\n   // New line
number // any positive number
\r\n   // New line
number // Positive number, .length < = 4
\r\n   // New line
```

What I want is to verify that the first zero is always present, If not, insert it to match the previous list format.

```
text  --> Insert a zero after this text
\r\n
4
\r\n
1234
\r\n
```

To...

```
text
\r\n
0     --> the inserted zero
\r\n
4
\r\n
1234
\r\n
```

So, I know I could use the `.Insert(index, string)` inside a loop, in fact I'm using a for to loop the list with a lot of ugly validations

```
public Regex isNumber = new Regex(@"^\d+$");

// When the list is been build and a possible match is found call this method:
private void CheckIfZeroMustBeAdded(List<string> stringList)
{
    int counter = 0;

    for (int i = stringList.Count - 1; i > 1; i--)
    {
        if (stringList[i].Equals(Environment.NewLine))
        {
            // Do nothing
        }
        else if (counter == 2) 
        {
            if (!stringList[i].Equals("0"))
            {
                stringList.Insert(i, string.Format("{0}{1}", Environment.NewLine,"0"));
                break;
            }
        }
        else if (ExtractionConst.isNumber.Match(stringList[i]).Success && !stringList[i].Equals("0")
        {
            // There are two numbers together
            counter++;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

but.. Is there any efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Post your attempted code, or a snippet representing how you're going about it, otherwise you're likely to get an answer that resembles what you already implemented.

Comment: Please include code in the question directly instead of hiding it behind paste links.

Comment: Or no answer and a wealth of downvotes...

Comment: Your code assumes that the list contains newlines as separate strings, but attempts to insert newlines as part of other strings. That seems like it can't work well.

Comment: More to the point, `counter` is never reset. You say "(could contains many times this pattern)", but once `counter` is set to 2, it will never get set to anything else.

Comment: When the list is being build I use the method CheckIfZeroMustBeAdded() when detects that's a match occurs

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for you is using `Regex`, try this:

```
//Add using System.Text.RegularExpressions first
string input = ....;// It's up to you
string output = Regex.Replace(input,"([^0])(\r\n([1-9]|\\d{2,})\r\n([1-9]|\\d{2,4})\r\n)","$1\r\n0$2");
```